# Android: First element list view acting weird

Tags: android, android-listview, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-view

In my Android application I have a ListView with 5 elements. I created a custom adapter, in order to change the background of some elements of the listView. For example, the second item of the list view is not ready yet, so I want to `setBackground(Color.Gray)`, so he can look like it's not done it. In order to do that, I Overrided the getView() method from ArrayAdapter in my custom adapter how it follows:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent); 
    if(!itensAvailable[position]) v.setBackgroundColor(Color.Gray);
    return v;
}
```

The weird thing is, no matter if I use the boolean `itensAvailable[position]` or `!itensAvailable[position]` the first element of the list always has it's background changed! All the others elements of the list are behaving like expected, except the first one. More weird than that, if I do 
`if(position == 2) v.setBackgroundColor(Color.Gray);`

it changes the background from the item in the position 2, and the first item as well! If I do

```
if(position == 2) {
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.Gray);
System.out.println(v.getText());
}
```

Even more weird! Only the text from the position 2 gets printed, not the text from the first item.

What is going on? Android bug? By the way, im testing it on a XOOM 3.2 Honeycomb device.

And obviously, if I comment this if code, the first item doens't has it's background changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very strange !
What happens if you write :

```
    @Override 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent); 
        if(!itensAvailable[position]) v.setBackgroundColor(Color.Gray);
        else v.setBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: haha it worked. I don't know why this else is required, but you sir, saved my day. Thank you

Comment: Else is required because, the convert view you get back in the getView method would have a older state and that's why it's getting mixed up.

Comment: the problem that I have now is that the separators dissapears when I change the background to Gray. I guess the separators are also going on this if else statement. I tryed to do something like instanceof but it didn't solve the problem. Any insights?

Comment: this separator is related to the isEnabled method, not the getView()

Comment: The behavior is note weired it is the normal way the list recycles its views. For performance reasons views are not inflated every time instead some views are reused. To calculate the size of the list the first three items get instantiated and measured. After that those three will be reused for the views that are actually shown. One of the created views has a changed background. And because the super class does not know this it won't change it back.

Comment: this is still bothering me in 2018 and this question and answer helped me resolve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain the weird behaviour. Can you try the following code and see if it solves your problem -

```
@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  if (convertView == null) {
     convertView = to the view to be displayed;
  }
  if(!itensAvailable[position]) convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.Gray);
  return convertView;
 }
```

Comment: The behavior is note weired it is the normal way the list recycles its views. For performance reasons views are not inflated every time instead some views are reused. To calculate the size of the list the first three items get instantiated and measured. After that those three will be reused for the views that are actually shown. One of the created views has a changed background. And because the super class does not know this it won't change it back.

Answer (score 0):

I Have the exact same issue. Strange indeed!

What worked for me is to remove the line

```
View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
```

and use instead -

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.__my__layout__, parent, false);
.... more view manipulations ....
```

hope it helps!